# VBScript: Syntax Error in FROM clause

Tags: sql, database, vbscript, connection

This is my first visit here.
I need help with connection to access db from vbscript, I will appreciate any clues!
This is my code:

```
connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\Gregory\Documents\db1.accdb"
set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
conn.Open connStr
rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rs.Open "SELECT username FROM User", conn
```

I should also add that there is just one table in the database, called "User" and it's got three fields: username, password and realName.

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: @user3786747 -- You have to have patience -- it's Saturday night (depending on where you are, of course).

Comment: This is what I am getting:
    Script error detected at line 19.
    Source line: rs.Open "SELECT username FROM User", conn
    Description: Syntax error in FROM clause.

Comment: You might need brackets in the rs.Open line.

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't work. I can hardly remember using parantheses in VBScript

Comment: I believe `User` is a reserved word in SQL. Try using `[]` around the table name: `select username from [User]`

Comment: Cool. I'll post it as an answer in case others have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `User` is a reserved word in SQL. Try using `[ ]` around the table name:

```
select username from [User]
```